# Automatically trigger grouped formatting commands in overlays

Tags: beamer, overlays

I would like output identical to the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[<+->]{Sampling}
\begin{itemize}
\item A random sample of ten people from the US will \alt<5>{{\color{blue}on average}}{on average} produce
five men and five women, but... \uncover<+->{ any given trial is likely to over-represent one sex and underrepresent
the other.}
\item Analogy: if you flip a fair coin 10 times, \alt<5>{{\color{blue}on average}}{on average} you'll get 5
heads and 5 tails, but... \uncover<+->{ sometimes we might get 7 heads and 3 tails, and other times 8 tails
and 2 heads.}
\item What does ``\alt<5>{{\color{blue}on average}}{on average}'' mean above?
\item It means that if we were to take a lot of samples.... blah blah.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, instead of `\alt<5>{{\color{blue}on average}}{on average}`, I want to lazily put `\groupA{on average}` for the first two instances of "on average", and on the third and last one something like `\revealGroupA{on average}`. That is, I want to write the following code but achieve the same output as above:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[<+->]{Sampling}
\begin{itemize}
\item A random sample of ten people from the US will \groupA{on average} produce
five men and five women, but... \uncover<+->{ any given trial is likely to over-represent one sex and underrepresent
the other.}
\item Analogy: if you flip a fair coin 10 times, \groupA{on average} you'll get 5
heads and 5 tails, but... \uncover<+->{ sometimes we might get 7 heads and 3 tails, and other times 8 tails
and 2 heads.}
\item What does ``\revealGroupA{on average}'' mean above?
\item It means that if we were to take a lot of samples.... blah blah.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Some notes:

- In the example, the argument ("on average") is always the same, but in other use cases that is not the case.
- I also do this a lot in math so it would be nice for the command to work in math and outside of it.
- I would likely use this mechanism in several different frames of the same file.
- Not sure if relevant, but I plan to extend the answer to also create a `\groupB` command, which would essentially do the same thing but use a different color. The reason for this is that I might want to use both `\groupA` and `\groupB` in the same frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `totcount` package to store the overlay number on which your group shall be revealed in-between compilations (don't reuse the same group on different frames):

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\slideinframe}{\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother

\usepackage{totcount}


\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}

\newcounter{overlaygroupA}
\setcounter{overlaygroupA}{0}

\newcommand{\revealGroupA}[1]{%
  \only<.>{\setcounter{overlaygroupA}{\slideinframe}}%
  \alert<.>{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\groupA}[1]{%
  \alert<\totvalue{overlaygroupA}>{#1}%
}

\regtotcounter{overlaygroupA}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[<+->]{Sampling}
\begin{itemize}
\item A random sample of ten people from the US will \groupA{on average} produce
five men and five women, but... \uncover<+->{ any given trial is likely to over-represent one sex and underrepresent
the other.}
\item Analogy: if you flip a fair coin 10 times, \groupA{on average} you'll get 5
heads and 5 tails, but... \uncover<+->{ sometimes we might get 7 heads and 3 tails, and other times 8 tails
and 2 heads.}
\item What does ``\revealGroupA{on average}'' mean above?
\item It means that if we were to take a lot of samples.... blah blah.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @scottkosty You're welcome!

Comment: By "don't reuse the same group on different frames" do you mean that I should only use this feature for one frame in the presentation? i.e., if I use this feature on frame 1, I need to define a new group if I want to use the feature on frame 2?

Comment: @scottkosty Yes, the name of the counter is global. If you use the same name on multiple frames, funny things might happen

Comment: If you don't insist on your syntax with the hard coded name, you could use the name of the group as an argument and thus making it more flexible.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I would prefer not to pass an argument if possible. Would it be possible to (1) either reset the counter at each frame, or (2) by default just use the frame number as the argument? If one of those is possible, should I ask a new question?

Comment: @scottkosty adding the framenumber to the counter name might be a possibility. You could try with a new question.

Comment: Sounds good, I posted the new answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680075/trigger-grouped-formatting-commands-in-overlays-on-multiple-frames. No worries at all if you don't have time/interest to take a look. You've already helped a lot and given a great base for achieving my ideal functionality. Thank you!