# Trigger grouped formatting commands in overlays on multiple frames

Tags: beamer, overlays

This question is a follow-up to the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/679551/12212). I would like a command on one overlay to "trigger" formatting of text on previous overlays within a frame. The extension I am asking about here is how to have a command that I can reuse across frames.

Below is an example that uses the mechanism from the referenced answer, but the mechanism expectedly relies on the command only being used on one frame. The output of the second frame is as expected, but the output of the first frame is not as desired because of this limitation.

I would like the commands `\docolorOnAA` and `\dotriggerAA` to each accept only one argument (as is currently the case). That is, I don't want to additionally pass a counter name or label as an argument.

EDIT: The document I will use this for is my lecture notes, which will have 900 frames, and I will use the provided commands in a non-trivial percentage of the frames (~20%) so hopefully there is a mechanism that scales well for a large document.

EDIT: I would like to use `pdflatex` to compile the document.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\omcolorA}[1]{\textcolor{teal} {#1}}
\newcommand{\omcolorB}[1]{\textcolor{purple} {#1}}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/679551/12212
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\slideinframe}{\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother

\usepackage{totcount}

\newcounter{overlaycolorOnAA}
\setcounter{overlaycolorOnAA}{0}
\newcounter{overlaycolorOnBB}
\setcounter{overlaycolorOnBB}{0}

\newcommand{\dotriggerAA}[1]{%
  \only<.>{\setcounter{overlaycolorOnAA}{\slideinframe}}%
  \alt<.>{\omcolorA{#1}}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\dotriggerBB}[1]{%
  \only<.>{\setcounter{overlaycolorOnBB}{\slideinframe}}%
  \alt<.>{\omcolorB{#1}}{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\docolorOnAA}[1]{%
  \alt<\totvalue{overlaycolorOnAA}>{\omcolorA{#1}}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\docolorOnBB}[1]{%
  \alt<\totvalue{overlaycolorOnBB}>{\omcolorB{#1}}{#1}%
}

\regtotcounter{overlaycolorOnAA}
\regtotcounter{overlaycolorOnBB}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[<+->]{Sampling}
\begin{itemize}
\item A random sample of ten people from the US will \docolorOnAA{on average} produce
five men and five women, but... \uncover<+->{ any given trial is likely to over-represent one sex and underrepresent
the other.}
\item Analogy: if you flip a fair coin 10 times, \docolorOnAA{on average} you'll get 5
heads and 5 tails, but... \uncover<+->{ sometimes we might get 7 heads and 3 tails, and other times 8 tails
and 2 heads.}
\item What does ``\dotriggerAA{on average}'' mean above?
\item It means that if we were to take a lot of samples.... blah blah.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[<+->]{Sampling}
\begin{itemize}
\item A random sample of ten people from the US will \docolorOnAA{on average} produce
five men and five women, but... \uncover<+->{ any given trial is likely to over-represent one sex and underrepresent
the other.}
\item Analogy: if you flip a fair coin 10 times, \docolorOnAA{on average} you'll get 5
heads and 5 tails, but... \uncover<+->{ sometimes we might get 7 heads and 3 tails, and other times 8 tails
and 2 heads.}
\item misc
\item misc
\item ...
\item What does ``\dotriggerAA{on average}'' mean above?
\item It means that if we were to take a lot of samples.... blah blah.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the slide number on which you want to reveal the group to the .aux file, and retrieve it on the second compilation.

In the following example, I defined three groups you can work with (e.g. `\groupA`,`\groupB`,`\groupC`). If you need more, replace the  `3` in the line `\loop\ifnum\value{MaxRevealGroup} < 3` with the desired number of groups (don't use a number bigger than 26).

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*\newreveal{\@newl@bel{revealgroup}}
\newcounter{MaxRevealGroup}

\newcommand*\NewRevealGroup[1]{
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname revealGroup#1\endcsname[1]{%
        \only<.>{\immediate\write\@auxout{%
                \string\newreveal{Group#1-Frame\theframenumber}{\the\beamer@slideinframe}}}%
        \alert<.>{##1}%
    }
    
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname group#1\endcsname[1]{%
        \ifcsname revealgroup@Group#1-Frame\theframenumber\endcsname
            \alert<\csname revealgroup@Group#1-Frame\theframenumber\endcsname>{##1}%
        \else
            ##1%
        \fi
    }
}
\loop\ifnum\value{MaxRevealGroup} < 3
    \stepcounter{MaxRevealGroup}
    \expandafter\NewRevealGroup\expandafter{\expanded{\Alph{MaxRevealGroup}}}
\repeat
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}[<+->]{Sampling}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item A random sample of ten people from the US will \groupA{on average} produce 
            five men and five women, but... \uncover<+->{ any given trial is likely to over-represent one sex and underrepresent
                the other.}
            \item Analogy: if you flip a fair coin 10 times, \groupA{on average} you'll get 5
            heads and 5 tails, but... \uncover<+->{ sometimes we might get 7 heads and 3 tails, and other times 8 tails
                and 2 heads.}
            \item What does ``\revealGroupA{on average}'' mean above?
            \item It means that if we were to take a lot of samples.... blah blah.
        \end{itemize}
        
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[<+->]{Sampling}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item A random sample of ten people from the US will \groupA{on average} produce 
            five men and five women, but... \uncover<+->{ any given trial is likely to over-represent one sex and underrepresent
                the other.}
            \item Analogy: if you flip a fair coin 10 times, \groupA{on average} you'll get 5
            heads and 5 tails, but... \uncover<+->{ sometimes we might get 7 heads and 3 tails, and other times 8 tails
                and 2 heads.}
            \item It means that if we were to take a lot of samples.... blah blah.
            \item What does ``\revealGroupA{on average}'' mean above?
        \end{itemize}
        
    \end{frame}
    
    
    \begin{frame}[<+->]{Sampling}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item A random sample of ten people from the US will \groupB{on average} produce 
            five men and five women, but... \uncover<+->{ any given trial is likely to over-represent one sex and underrepresent
                the other.}
            \item Analogy: if you flip a fair coin 10 times, \groupB{on average} you'll get 5
            heads and 5 tails, but... \uncover<+->{ sometimes we might get 7 heads and 3 tails, and other times 8 tails
                and 2 heads.}
            \item What does ``\revealGroupB{on average}'' mean above?
            \item It means that if we were to take a lot of samples.... blah blah.
        \end{itemize}
        
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Edit

With the following code, each group is revealed with a different color. The colors are specified in the list `\RrvealGroupColorsList` at the beginning of the preamble (the number of groups that are defined is the number of colors in the list).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand*\RrvealGroupColorsList{teal,purple,orange}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\newreveal{\@newl@bel{revealgroup}}

\newcommand*\NewRevealGroup[2]{
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname revealGroup#1\endcsname[1]{%
        \only<.>{\immediate\write\@auxout{%
                \string\newreveal{Group#1-Frame\theframenumber}{\the\beamer@slideinframe}}}%
        \alt<.>{\textcolor{#2}{##1}}{##1}%
    }
    
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname group#1\endcsname[1]{%
        \@ifundefined{revealgroup@Group#1-Frame\theframenumber}{%
            ##1%
        }{%
            \alt<\csname revealgroup@Group#1-Frame\theframenumber\endcsname>{\textcolor{#2}{##1}}{##1}%
        }%
    }
}

\newcounter{RevealGroup}
\@for\group@color:=\RrvealGroupColorsList\do{
    \stepcounter{RevealGroup}
    \@expandtwoargs\NewRevealGroup{\Alph{RevealGroup}}{\group@color}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}[<+->]{Sampling}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item A random sample of ten \groupB{people} from the US will \groupA{on average} \groupC{produce} 
            five men and five women, but... \uncover<+->{ any given trial is likely to over-represent one sex and underrepresent
                the other.}
            \item Analogy: if you flip a fair coin 10 times, \groupA{on average} you'll \revealGroupC{get 5}
            heads and 5 tails, but... \uncover<+->{ sometimes we might get 7 heads and 3 tails, and other times 8 tails
                and 2 heads.}
            \item What does ``\revealGroupA{on average}'' mean above? \revealGroupB{blah blah}.
            \item It means that if we were to take a lot of samples.... 
        \end{itemize}
        
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[<+->]{Sampling}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item A random sample of ten people from the US will \groupA{on average} produce 
            five men and five women, but... \uncover<+->{ any given trial is likely to over-represent one sex and underrepresent
                the other.}
            \item Analogy: if you flip a fair coin 10 times, \groupA{on average} you'll get 5
            heads and 5 tails, but... \uncover<+->{ sometimes we might get 7 heads and 3 tails, and other times 8 tails
                and 2 heads.}
            \item It means that if we were to take a lot of samples.... blah blah.
            \item What does ``\revealGroupA{on average}'' mean above?
        \end{itemize}
        
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works great, thank you! I'm shocked that (1) you were able to understand exactly what I wanted (since I don't think what I wrote was clear); (2) you implemented it in such few lines of code and (3) from quick testing it doesn't seem to add much to compilation time. Now I just need to spend some time studying your code :).

Comment: One minor comment for anyone who might want to use this code in the future: I'm going to append "|handout:0" inside the overlay argument of the two `alt`s, since I don't want the coloring when I use the "handout" class option of beamer.

Comment: @scottkosty I'm happy you liked the solution. I've replaced `\ifcsname` with `\if@undefined` for a safer test and used `\@expandtwoargs` to simplify things a bit.

Comment: `\onslide<+->{}` seems to disrupt the behavior. e.g., if I replace `What does` in the example with `\onslide<+->{What does}` then the group is revealed one overlay later than I prefer. i.e., I would still want the group to be revealed on the first time the text in the arg to `\revealGroupA` is shown. Any idea for a fix? No worries if you don't have time. Also let me know if you prefer for me to start a separate question or if you would like to see a real use case of `\onslide<+->{}`. By the way, I've been using the solution already for several lecture slides and it's worked very smoothly!

Comment: @scottkosty Does using `\onslide<.(1)->{What does}` solve your problem? It might be possible to change the definition of `\revealGroupA` so it would also get layout specification, but I don't know if it will be straight forward. IMHO my suggestion is the simplest way to get what you want, but I will need to think about it.

Comment: @scottkosty Another possible solution would be to wrap `\alt<.>{\textcolor{#2}{##1}}{##1}` in the definition of `\revealGroup#1` with `\uncover<.->`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will play around with that.

Answer (score 2):

Here a semi-manual approach which includes the frame number in the counter name.

You will have to manually maintain the list of frames, which use this feature, under the comment `% list all frames here on which you use the overlay groups`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{totcount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\slideinframe}{\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\revealGroupA}[1]{%
  \only<1>{
    \newcounter{overlaygroupA-\insertframenumber}
    \setcounter{overlaygroupA-\insertframenumber}{0}
  }
  \only<.>{\setcounter{overlaygroupA-\insertframenumber}{\slideinframe}}%
  \alert<.>{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\groupA}[1]{%
  \alert<\totvalue{overlaygroupA-\insertframenumber}>{#1}%
}

% list all frames here on which you use the overlay groups
\regtotcounter{overlaygroupA-1}
\regtotcounter{overlaygroupA-2}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[<+->]{Sampling}
\begin{itemize}
\item A random sample of ten people from the US will \groupA{on average} produce
five men and five women, but... \uncover<+->{ any given trial is likely to over-represent one sex and underrepresent
the other.}
\item Analogy: if you flip a fair coin 10 times, \groupA{on average} you'll get 5
heads and 5 tails, but... \uncover<+->{ sometimes we might get 7 heads and 3 tails, and other times 8 tails
and 2 heads.}
\item What does ``\revealGroupA{on average}'' mean above?
\item It means that if we were to take a lot of samples.... blah blah.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[<+->]{Next Frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item A random sample of ten people from the US will \groupA{on average} produce
five men and five women, but... \uncover<+->{ any given trial is likely to over-represent one sex and underrepresent
the other.}
\item What does ``\revealGroupA{on average}'' mean above?
\item It means that if we were to take a lot of samples.... blah blah.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 thank you, it works well! However the presentation I need this for has a lot of slides. I'm sorry I didn't add that information (I'll edit it in now). I will start a bounty on this question as soon as it's eligible.